# Symfony2 - Sonata Datagrid filter operators translation fails for doctrine_orm_class field

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, sonata-admin, sonata

In my Symfony project (2.5.7) I use Sonata Admin Bundle 2.3. In Admin class I specified my DataGridForm as follows:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagrid)    
{    
$datagrid    
->add('name')    
->add('created_by_user');    
}
```

Where `name` is text and `created_by_user` is one-to-many relation to user class.
As a result I have beautiful filters form but operators at `created_by_user` field, which are label_type_equals and label_type_not_equals, are not translated. 
Translations are provided for the other field: `name`: label_type_contains, label_type_not_contains, label_type_equals, which is good.

In my app/config/config.yml I set:

```
framework:    
   translator: { fallback: "pl" }
```

The translations are provided by SonataAdminBundle in SonataAdminBundle.pl.xliff, located in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/translations.

Any other label is translated. Only the ones connected to doctrine_orm_class type are not.

Please give me some idea to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I upgraded the packages the missing translations occured. I upgraded to 
SonataAdminBundle 2.3.3, but I'm not so sure about this was the solution. Nevertheless I'm not able to repeate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The translation file for *SonataAdminBundle* is for "internal global" messages.

You could add your translations to your default file which should be located at *Resources/translations/messages.pl.yml* file to add translations.

But the recommended way is to create a separate file for one bundle or even one admin file:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/getting_started.html#step-3-create-an-admin-service

Using the *TranslationDomain* you could add a global file e.g. "YourBundle.pl.yml" or a "MyAdmin.pl.yml":

```
# Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml
services:
    sonata.admin.post:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Post" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [AcmeDemoBundle]]
```

Comment: Of course I did those basic steps. As I wrote before Sonata provided those labels in Polish.